# Why is Safari not allowing a form element after template element?

Tags: html, safari

A `<form>` element inside a `<template>` element will cause the next form element to be removed from DOM in all latest versions of Safari.

As you can see in the demo, the `<form>` element is removed while the form's content is still visible. If you comment out the `<template>` element, the form displays correctly. Why would this happen?

Demo (Safari only): http://codepen.io/achisholm/pen/eBxjyX?editors=1100

Comment: Seems like you found a bug in the WebKit HTML parser that should be reported at https://bugs.webkit.org/

Comment: I have the exact same issue as well. I can see that your original bug report has been marked as duplicate, but the active bug report/status can be found here: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=158386